# Getting "[Errno 14] Bad address" when using Trickle with AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, trickle

I'm trying to use Trickle with AWS CLI S3. When I run a sync command without Trickle, everything goes through without error (but I'm hitting my host's bandwidth limits). When I run the same command with trickle I get the following output and my script shuts down:

```
[Errno 14] Bad address
```

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
trickle -u 3000 /usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync /local/path s3://s3/path --delete
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the `-s` flag to make trickle run "standalone" and everything started working fine.